# Calculation of Time in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three text box on a website i.e., Start_Time, End_Time and I want the result in the third textbox immediately after filling both the above-mentioned text box.

Example:

Start_Time = 10:00

End_Time = 12:00

Total Time = 02:00

Note: Result should be in hh:mm.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us?

Comment: Ans see https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html

Comment: What did you try? Please provide any code. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Set it According to your Text boxes. As You didn't mentioned details but it will do your work what u want to achieve. Its a Sample Code

```
        string startTime = "11:00";
        string endTime = "14:00";

        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));

        Console.WriteLine(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<label>start time</label>
<textarea id="start_time" onchange="getTotal()"> </textarea>

 <label>end time</label>
 <textarea id="end_time" onchange="getTotal()"> </textarea>

 <label>total time</label>
 <textarea id="tot_time"> </textarea>
```

And the javascript will be something similar to this:

```
<script>
    function getTotal() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end_time").value;

        if ((start != " ") && (end != " ")) {
            start = start.trim();
            end = end.trim();
            var tot = TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(end).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(start));
            document.getElementById("tot_date").value = tot;
        }
    }
</script>
```